# Change value of class attribute in html using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, dom

I want to change this line:

```
    <li id="activehome" ><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
```

to

```
    <li id="activehome" class="active"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
```

Adding that class attribute. How do I do this using Javascript or even Jquery will do. Thanks in advance. The line should be changed when the page loads.

Comment: Show what did you try so far and others will help you to fix it.

Comment: Have you tired anything or simply asking your question without trying anything ? show what you tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery, using [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/):

```
$('#activehome').addClass('active');
```

pure JS, using [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute):

```
document.getElementById('activehome').setAttribute('class', 'active');
```

or using [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className)

```
document.getElementById('activehome').className = 'active';
```

Comment: I have tried this. It doesn't work. The idea behing it is I have a navigation bar which I call in different pages. So I have put the code for navigation bar in a file nav.php and called it using include in my index.php. I want to use JS or JQuery to change the Home button to active or for any button on any page where I call this nav bar. If there is a better solution please suggest me that.

Comment: Yes it works according to the information you have given. Please update your question with enough information for us to answer this for your situation - My assumption is you have multiple IDs with activehome

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? You need to be more specific.

Comment: Hey sorry! It worked after I wrote it inside onload. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

$("#activehome").addClass('active');
$("#activehome > a").text('Home');